# Distinct by product id

Tags: c#

Below is my class.

```
public class MyGroceryListItems
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am fetching from database the values for this class and putting those classes in `IList<MyGroceryListItems>`. However, there are some duplicate items with same `id` but different quantity. How can I fetch only distinct entries by `id`?

I tried list.distinct but that didn't work because not all the entries are same in the record having same product id.

Comment: If there are multiple entries with the same ID, which one do you want to fetch?

Comment: Why would you have multiple entries with the same ID? If it's the same ID, it should be the same object, otherwise it isn't really and ID.

Comment: Though @Spender could give an answer which is what you needed , still i feel there is something wrong with the design . Same product id with different quantities doesnt sound good. For eg. in a real world scenario if you buy 2 bread packets you wont see in a bill that bread packet quantity 1 price 5 $ and bread packet quantity 1 price 5 $ twice. INstead you would see something like bread packet quantity 2 price 10 $. Your scenario is something like the first one in the example . Though it is out of the topic , i just wanted to point out that still you can redesign it.

Comment: @srsyogesh, recently i was in shop and bought 2 bags to carry items i bought, after they pass the cashbox, i suddenly decide to take 1 more.. here we have "first scenario" =D

Comment: @srsyogesh: I added something to the end of my post which addresses this concern.

Comment: @sinatr : that was a nice one , i didn't thought about it :(

Comment: @sinatr : i just thought another scenario , if you would have paid the cash and billed already may be next purchase is considered as a new bill , else the cashier just increase the number of quantity of bags by one isnt it (i.e three) instead of adding a new item ?

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<MyGroceryListItems> items = ...;
var uniqueItemsByProdId = 
      items.GroupBy(x => x.ProductId).Select(g => g.First());
```

This will pick off a single (and somewhat arbitrary) item in the case that more than a item shares a ProductId with another.

Alternatively (and slightly faster), you could use a `DistinctBy` extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> 
        DistinctBy<T,TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T,TKey> selector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> hs = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach(var item in src)
    {
        //Add returns false if item is already in set
        if(hs.Add(selector(item)))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

like this:

```
 items.DistinctBy(x => x.ProductId)
```

More useful, perhaps, is a query that gives the aggregate quantities for each item by ProductId:

```
 items
   .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
   .Select(g => new MyGroceryListItems{
                      g.Key.ProductId,
                      g.Key.ProductName,
                      Quantity = g.Sum(gg => gg.Quantity)
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an equality comparer. There is a solid example on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb338049.aspx

This will give you more control over which items you consider *equal*. But involves more coding. If you want to select single and somewhat random item from all the items which share an id, then you'll be better off with **spender**'s solution